# How do I call a custom control javascript with a conditional updatepanel on my aspx?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I've a custom control created where I render tabs.
On the page load method of the tab control I use the following:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnLoad(e);

    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.Append("Sys.Application.add_load(pageLoad);");
    str.Append("function pageLoad(event, args) {");
    str.AppendFormat("$(\"#{0}\")", this.ClientID);
    str.Append(".tabs({ beforeActivate: function(e,ui) {");
    str.Append(CustomJSInSelectedTab);
    str.Append(GetSetSelectedTabIndexScript());
    str.Append("},");
    str.Append(String.Format("active: {0}", indexOf(_hdnSelectedTabId.Value)));
    str.Append("});");

    str.Append("}");

    ScriptUtility.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, "_INITTABS", str.ToString());
}

private int indexOf(string p) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_hdnSelectedTabId.Value))
        return 0;
    int i = 0;
    foreach (FlowTabItem t in Tabs)
    {
        string id = t.ControlID;
        if (id.Equals(p))
            return i;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The purpose of this code is to keep the selected tab the same after a postback occurs. This works fine on a normal aspx page, but If i have a updatepanel of this kind

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
    ...
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I hit the page load of the controller and I get an updated hdd value as expected but it doesn't override the js on the page as it does when I don't have the updatePanel.

Any idea/suggestion or maybe a workarround?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `UpdatePanel` control, the `RegisterStartupScript` method doesn't work. To make it work when inside `UpdatePanel` use the following piece of code. This is tested and works perfectly fine in our application.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page, page.GetType(), "TestScript", "alert(1)", true);
```

Comment: Don't you need to add a asp:ScriptManager in the aspx page to make your code work?

Comment: `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` here is the static method of the [`ScriptManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) class. When you're using `UpdatePanel` then you already have a `ScriptManager` added to the page. Here in the code the `ScriptManager` is not referring to the instance of the `ScriptManager` class.

Comment: Ok, great! Thank you for the explanation

Comment: Good morning, thanks it works! is there any side problems for switching scripts?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by *switching scripts*? Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: sorry, I meant methods (RegisterClientScriptBlock for RegisterStartupScript)

Comment: No side effects whatsoever.

Comment: Alright mate, thank you very much, I've learned something new today thanks to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not exactly what you want, but you can get good ideas from it :
[UpdatePanels and ClientScript in custom Controls](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2006/Dec/12/UpdatePanels-and-ClientScript-in-custom-Controls)